# Unresponsive hiring manager and HR following no show interview

Tags: interviewing

I am really irritated right now, my application was accepted and I had a scheduled phone interview with a large corporate brand.

First the hiring manager rescheduled the interview time, then on the day did not bother to show up. I proceeded to contact HR after 15 minutes of waiting via email, heard nothing. I then phoned and left a voice mail asking whether the interview was still on, heard nothing. Next day (Today), heard nothing from HR.

My questions are the following:

1. Should I chase HR up or withdraw my application? I am in two minds now about this opportunity. On one hand it is a global brand, and for that reason alone I want to pursue it but than on the other hand, I am so extremely irritated that if I took the brand name away in any other circumstances I would withdraw my application. I have other options, job offers etc.
2. Why have HR suddenly gone cold, it is striking me as extremely unprofessional and disorganised? Has anyone on here experienced something similar?
3. If I complain, and do get an interview, are my chances blown? Is it better to wait and let them come back to me.

Current circumstance: I accepted a job offer elsewere, serving my notice period, so cannot wait forever for these guys to make a decision.

Comment: Interviews are not just for the company to evaluate you but for you to evaluate the company as well. It sounds to me like the hiring manager "blew the interview" by choosing not to show up. Why would you still want to work for a place like that?

Comment: @DanK strength of the brand, it is a blue chip. Only reason.

Comment: Problem is, this blue chip company *knows* it is a blue chip company and has adjusted its behavior accordingly.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri by not attending scheduled interviews? How do they hire people? But yes, they do come across as extremely arrogant, disappointing - it's not the way to treat people and has left a bad impression.

Comment: Yes, by not attending scheduled interviews, offering a less than competitive salary, ignoring your starting date preference, etc. Then, once you are hired, by not holding promised performance reviews, denying vacation requests, taking away your red stapler, and in general acting like they're doing you a great favor just by letting you work there.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri sounds like I have dodged a bullet. I think salary expectations might have put them off, company 1 are offering a good salary, I put that on the HR form. Will never know.

Comment: "Interviews are ... for you to evaluate the company" - absolutely. I once had an on-site interview with a blue chip company that was a disaster from start to finish. The interviewer kept me waiting outside his office for 2 hours because of some "panic" that he needed to sort out. That was actually useful, because it soon became obvious just from watching and listening that *none* of his team had any respect for him. The final insult was "well, you only live 20 miles away, so we don't need to pay you any expenses, do we?" (and they didn't even provide any lunch during a whole-day session!). ...

Comment: ... they arranged a second interview, at which I was the one who just didn't show up. I eventually got a rejection letter from them - no surprise about that, except it took them literally 9 months to write and send it!

Comment: @alephzero I wonder if it was the same blue chip company. Wouldn't surprise me if it was.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager different situation, the guy at least had an interview.

Comment: @DanK OP might be a big fan of having a job.

Comment: @corsiKa you've hit the nail on the head. Had respect and admiration for the blue chip until this experience.

Comment: @bobo2000 Yeah, and in all honesty it really sucks when someone is a hardworking, honest, productive person just trying to provide for themselves and their family and the current system seems to be "spam your resume and hope you get through" - we just posted a role at my firm and have almost 100 responses in a couple days. How many of these applications are rock stars we'll never see because the lack of some keyword caused them to not get on the short-list? It's not cost effective to interview them all!

Comment: @corsiKa the trouble is I was shortlisted and had a phone interview scheduled so obviously was good enough, hiring manager didn't bother showing up with the HR going AWOL. Based on who is already working there, not sure if the company is making the correct hiring decisions.

Comment: @corsiKa well 3 days and counting they haven't bothered to get in touch. Very shocking at how unprofessional this blue chip is. Totally changed my perception of them.

Comment: Update: company got back to me after 2 weeks. I decided to interview anyway for the experience, passed phone interview and into the final round. They were extremely apologetic.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You've followed up and for whatever reason they haven't gotten back to you. There can be lots of reasons for this and, short of finding a good mind reader, I doubt you'll ever truly know why. Things definitely move a lot slower in the hiring process than you expect but to be honest given their unprofessional behavior I'd suggest you've dodged a bullet there.

I definitely wouldn't bother complaining - I doubt it would achieve anything and even if they then interview you and offer you the job. Do you really want to start off your working relationship with them on a *complaint*?

You've got another offer elsewhere which you have accepted so I'd move on and focus on the new job (congratulations by the way!).

Answer (score 11):

> Should I chase HR up or withdraw my application?

Neither.

Focus on the offer you have already accepted. Leave your application open and wait until this company gets back to you. If they don't reply, just cross them off your list.

> Current circumstance: accepted a job offer elseware, serving my notice
>   period, so cannot wait forever for these guys to make a decision.

Very strange.

You accepted an offer elsewhere, but are continuing to chase an interview at this new company?

Perhaps they got wind of the fact that you already committed to a different job and don't want to pursue someone who changes their mind so quickly.

Comment: He has nothing to lose by attending another interview

Comment: @JoeStrazzere So how exactly does he go back on his word in this case? He hasn't even had the chance to exchange a word with the company ;) It's not strange to apply at different companies at all.

Comment: I applied to both companies at the same time, this was my first choice originally so decided to explore the opportunity once it presented itself. Their application process was also very long and protracted.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm not legally binded to the company unless I sign an employment contract. Also my offer is conditional, so it goes both ways. I agree it's good practice to not do this, and under normal circumstances, I would never do this. The second company is a blue chip.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Customarily you show up for your interview though... I don't think OP owes the company anything in this case.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere in the UK yes that is how it works. It's not uncommon for people to withdraw their offers and accept another. I didn't even get the chance to weigh up both offers since the blue chip's recruitment process is long and protracted. Either way, it looks like the original company has benefited.

Comment: @bobo2000 My experience in the UK is that it is *very* uncommon for people to withdraw from an accepted offer and accept another.  I would not want to hire somebody who would do that.

Comment: @MartinBonner it happens very rarely, but it does happen when people are offered their dream roles.I personally have never done it, but if tomorrow Google or Facebook came knocking on my door giving me a good offer, I would be stupid to turn them down. This situation is similar.

Comment: @bobo2000 : Yes, I can imagine it happens, however I was responding to your comment was "it is not uncommon" - it *is* uncommon.

Comment: Fair enough Martin

Answer (score 4):

Usually when HR goes cold like this, it means they have made a decision and are not wasting time on candidates they have rejected. However that usually does not involve not showing up for a scheduled interview without cancelling it.

What may have happened is that someone had a family emergency and forgot to cancel. It may be the tone of your contact concerning the cancellation that caused them not to respond to you further or they may just be busy with higher priorities than that particular job. Sometimes it means that the person who was handling it has left the company and no one else is even seeing your emails. Things get dropped through the cracks sometimes in large corporations. Sometimes they stop all hiring for budget reasons or because of upcoming problems such as a layoff in the planning stage.

Yes, they should have contacted you to tell you the interview was cancelled, but as I said, sometimes things get dropped through the cracks. Assuming an honest mistake is always more productive than getting mad.

In any event, you have contacted them as you should have done, but no one can force an answer. If you have a second contact name, I would try that but make sure your tone is not negative. You are perplexed at what has happened and perhaps the email got mislaid, not mad at the whole thing.  Attitude in an email like this is critical.

Since you have another job offer, I personally would just move on.

Comment: Doubt the HR contact has left the company, I just think they are incompetent. I have accepted that I am not going to work for these people, the lack of professionalism and arrogance is really just irritating for such a global brand.

Comment: @bobo2000, it is not good to assume incompetence. If the tone of your initial inquiry about the interview made it clear you were angry and thought they were incompetent, that alone would stop the process for you because no one wants to work with angry people.

Comment: No it wasn't , I simply asked if there was anything wrong and if the interview was still on. At the end of the day it is incompetence, where in comparison to the job role I accepted there was similarly a delay but HR were quick to deal with it. Apologising. On this occasion I had every right to be angry, I followed the process and they did not act professionally to the point that I have still not heard from them. No excuses.